# Issue with Javascript calc function running twice

Tags: php, javascript

I am fairly new to Javascript, i generally use php for most things, but i need a dynamic calculation for my site and i am having some trouble figuring it out.
I have a table of numbers that has up to 10 text entry fields per row and 10 text entry fields per column.  I wrote a function that calculates the total of the numbers entered per row and tried to use the same function to calculate the columns as well, but it is not displaying.  Any help that you can provide would be great.  My code is below.

```
function calcTotal(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,SUM) {

  var one = Number(document.getElementById(A).value);

  var two = Number(document.getElementById(B).value);

  var three = Number(document.getElementById(C).value);

  var four = Number(document.getElementById(D).value);

  var five = Number(document.getElementById(E).value);

  var six = Number(document.getElementById(F).value);

  var seven = Number(document.getElementById(G).value);

  var eight = Number(document.getElementById(H).value);

  var nine = Number(document.getElementById(I).value);

  var ten = Number(document.getElementById(J).value);


  var ans = one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten;
  document.getElementById(SUM).innerHTML = ans;

}   

echo '<form name"score" class="form-vertical" action="" method="post">';

                echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed' align='center'>";   
                echo '<tr> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Roller</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 1</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 2</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 3</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 4</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 5</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 6</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 7</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 8</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 9</th> <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Frame 10</th><th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Total</th></tr>';      
                 $i=1;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sroll)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">'.$row['name'].'</td>'; 
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$i.'rname" value="'.$row['name'].'"/>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame1" id="'.$i.'f1" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n2f1\',\'nf1\',\'1f1\',\'2f1\',\'3f1\',\'4f1\',\'5f1\',\'6f1\',\'7f1\',\'f1result\')"/></td>';          
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame2" id="'.$i.'f2" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f2\',\'n2f2\',\'nf2\',\'1f2\',\'2f2\',\'3f2\',\'4f2\',\'5f2\',\'6f2\',\'7f2\',\'f2result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame3" id="'.$i.'f3" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f3\',\'n2f3\',\'nf3\',\'1f3\',\'2f3\',\'3f3\',\'4f3\',\'5f3\',\'6f3\',\'7f3\',\'f3result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame4" id="'.$i.'f4" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f4\',\'n2f4\',\'nf4\',\'1f4\',\'2f4\',\'3f4\',\'4f4\',\'5f4\',\'6f4\',\'7f4\',\'f4result\')"/></td>';      
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame5" id="'.$i.'f5" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f5\',\'n2f5\',\'nf5\',\'1f5\',\'2f5\',\'3f5\',\'4f5\',\'5f5\',\'6f5\',\'7f5\',\'f5result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame6" id="'.$i.'f6" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f6\',\'n2f6\',\'nf6\',\'1f6\',\'2f6\',\'3f6\',\'4f6\',\'5f6\',\'6f6\',\'7f6\',\'f6result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame7" id="'.$i.'f7" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f7\',\'n2f7\',\'nf7\',\'1f7\',\'2f7\',\'3f7\',\'4f7\',\'5f7\',\'6f7\',\'7f7\',\'f7result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame8" id="'.$i.'f8" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f8\',\'n2f8\',\'nf8\',\'1f8\',\'2f8\',\'3f8\',\'4f8\',\'5f8\',\'6f8\',\'7f8\',\'f8result\')"/></td>';  
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame9" id="'.$i.'f9" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f9\',\'n2f9\',\'nf9\',\'1f9\',\'2f9\',\'3f9\',\'4f9\',\'5f9\',\'6f9\',\'7f9\',\'f9result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="'.$i.'Frame10" id="'.$i.'f10" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\''.$i.'f1\',\''.$i.'f2\',\''.$i.'f3\',\''.$i.'f4\',\''.$i.'f5\',\''.$i.'f6\',\''.$i.'f7\',\''.$i.'f8\',\''.$i.'f9\',\''.$i.'f10\',\''.$i.'result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f10\',\'n2f10\',\'nf10\',\'1f10\',\'2f10\',\'3f10\',\'4f10\',\'5f10\',\'6f10\',\'7f10\',\'f10result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="'.$i.'result"></div></td>';                    

                echo '</tr>';
                $i++;
                }
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newname" maxlength="30"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame1" id="nf1" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n2f1\',\'nf1\',\'1f1\',\'2f1\',\'3f1\',\'4f1\',\'5f1\',\'6f1\',\'7f1\',\'f1result\')"/></td>'; 
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame2" id="nf2" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f2\',\'n2f2\',\'nf2\',\'1f2\',\'2f2\',\'3f2\',\'4f2\',\'5f2\',\'6f2\',\'7f2\',\'f2result\')"/></td>'; 
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame3" id="nf3" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f3\',\'n2f3\',\'nf3\',\'1f3\',\'2f3\',\'3f3\',\'4f3\',\'5f3\',\'6f3\',\'7f3\',\'f3result\')"/></td>'; 
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame4" id="nf4" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f4\',\'n2f4\',\'nf4\',\'1f4\',\'2f4\',\'3f4\',\'4f4\',\'5f4\',\'6f4\',\'7f4\',\'f4result\')"/></td>';     
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame5" id="nf5" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f5\',\'n2f5\',\'nf5\',\'1f5\',\'2f5\',\'3f5\',\'4f5\',\'5f5\',\'6f5\',\'7f5\',\'f5result\')"/></td>'; 
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame6" id="nf6" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f6\',\'n2f6\',\'nf6\',\'1f6\',\'2f6\',\'3f6\',\'4f6\',\'5f6\',\'6f6\',\'7f6\',\'f6result\')"/></td>';     
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame7" id="nf7" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f7\',\'n2f7\',\'nf7\',\'1f7\',\'2f7\',\'3f7\',\'4f7\',\'5f7\',\'6f7\',\'7f7\',\'f7result\')"/></td>';     
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame8" id="nf8" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f8\',\'n2f8\',\'nf8\',\'1f8\',\'2f8\',\'3f8\',\'4f8\',\'5f8\',\'6f8\',\'7f8\',\'f8result\')"/></td>'; 
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame9" id="nf9" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f9\',\'n2f9\',\'nf9\',\'1f9\',\'2f9\',\'3f9\',\'4f9\',\'5f9\',\'6f9\',\'7f9\',\'f9result\')"/></td>';     
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="newFrame10" id="nf10" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'nf1\',\'nf2\',\'nf3\',\'nf4\',\'nf5\',\'nf6\',\'nf7\',\'nf8\',\'nf9\',\'nf10\',\'nresult\'); calcTotal(\'n3f10\',\'n2f10\',\'nf10\',\'1f10\',\'2f10\',\'3f10\',\'4f10\',\'5f10\',\'6f10\',\'7f10\',\'f10result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="nresult"></div></td>';

                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2name" maxlength="30"/></td>';       
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame1" id="n2f1" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n2f1\',\'nf1\',\'1f1\',\'2f1\',\'3f1\',\'4f1\',\'5f1\',\'6f1\',\'7f1\',\'f1result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame2" id="n2f2" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f2\',\'n2f2\',\'nf2\',\'1f2\',\'2f2\',\'3f2\',\'4f2\',\'5f2\',\'6f2\',\'7f2\',\'f2result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame3" id="n2f3" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f3\',\'n2f3\',\'nf3\',\'1f3\',\'2f3\',\'3f3\',\'4f3\',\'5f3\',\'6f3\',\'7f3\',\'f3result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame4" id="n2f4" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f4\',\'n2f4\',\'nf4\',\'1f4\',\'2f4\',\'3f4\',\'4f4\',\'5f4\',\'6f4\',\'7f4\',\'f4result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame5" id="n2f5" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f5\',\'n2f5\',\'nf5\',\'1f5\',\'2f5\',\'3f5\',\'4f5\',\'5f5\',\'6f5\',\'7f5\',\'f5result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame6" id="n2f6" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f6\',\'n2f6\',\'nf6\',\'1f6\',\'2f6\',\'3f6\',\'4f6\',\'5f6\',\'6f6\',\'7f6\',\'f6result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame7" id="n2f7" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f7\',\'n2f7\',\'nf7\',\'1f7\',\'2f7\',\'3f7\',\'4f7\',\'5f7\',\'6f7\',\'7f7\',\'f7result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame8" id="n2f8" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f8\',\'n2f8\',\'nf8\',\'1f8\',\'2f8\',\'3f8\',\'4f8\',\'5f8\',\'6f8\',\'7f8\',\'f8result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame9" id="n2f9" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f9\',\'n2f9\',\'nf9\',\'1f9\',\'2f9\',\'3f9\',\'4f9\',\'5f9\',\'6f9\',\'7f9\',\'f9result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new2Frame10" id="n2f10" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n2f1\',\'n2f2\',\'n2f3\',\'n2f4\',\'n2f5\',\'n2f6\',\'n2f7\',\'n2f8\',\'n2f9\',\'n2f10\',\'n2result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f10\',\'n2f10\',\'nf10\',\'1f10\',\'2f10\',\'3f10\',\'4f10\',\'5f10\',\'6f10\',\'7f10\',\'f10result\')"/></td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="n2result"></div></td>';

                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3name" maxlength="30"/></td>';       
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame1" id="n3f1" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n2f1\',\'nf1\',\'1f1\',\'2f1\',\'3f1\',\'4f1\',\'5f1\',\'6f1\',\'7f1\',\'f1result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame2" id="n3f2" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f2\',\'n2f2\',\'nf2\',\'1f2\',\'2f2\',\'3f2\',\'4f2\',\'5f2\',\'6f2\',\'7f2\',\'f2result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame3" id="n3f3" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f3\',\'n2f3\',\'nf3\',\'1f3\',\'2f3\',\'3f3\',\'4f3\',\'5f3\',\'6f3\',\'7f3\',\'f3result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame4" id="n3f4" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f4\',\'n2f4\',\'nf4\',\'1f4\',\'2f4\',\'3f4\',\'4f4\',\'5f4\',\'6f4\',\'7f4\',\'f4result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame5" id="n3f5" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f5\',\'n2f5\',\'nf5\',\'1f5\',\'2f5\',\'3f5\',\'4f5\',\'5f5\',\'6f5\',\'7f5\',\'f5result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame6" id="n3f6" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f6\',\'n2f6\',\'nf6\',\'1f6\',\'2f6\',\'3f6\',\'4f6\',\'5f6\',\'6f6\',\'7f6\',\'f6result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame7" id="n3f7" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f7\',\'n2f7\',\'nf7\',\'1f7\',\'2f7\',\'3f7\',\'4f7\',\'5f7\',\'6f7\',\'7f7\',\'f7result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame8" id="n3f8" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f8\',\'n2f8\',\'nf8\',\'1f8\',\'2f8\',\'3f8\',\'4f8\',\'5f8\',\'6f8\',\'7f8\',\'f8result\')"/></td>';    
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame9" id="n3f9" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f9\',\'n2f9\',\'nf9\',\'1f9\',\'2f9\',\'3f9\',\'4f9\',\'5f9\',\'6f9\',\'7f9\',\'f9result\')"/></td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><input class="span12" type="text" name="new3Frame10" id="n3f10" maxlength="2" size="2" onkeypress="validate(event)" onChange="calcTotal(\'n3f1\',\'n3f2\',\'n3f3\',\'n3f4\',\'n3f5\',\'n3f6\',\'n3f7\',\'n3f8\',\'n3f9\',\'n3f10\',\'n3result\'); calcTotal(\'n3f10\',\'n2f10\',\'nf10\',\'1f10\',\'2f10\',\'3f10\',\'4f10\',\'5f10\',\'6f10\',\'7f10\',\'f10result\')"/></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="n3result"></div></td>';

                echo '</tr>';
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">Total</td>';        
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f1result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f2result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f3result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f4result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f5result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f6result"></div></td>';       
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f7result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f8result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f9result"></div></td>';   
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="f10result"></div></td>';  
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;"><div id="totalresult"></div></td>';                    

                echo '</tr>';

                 echo '</table>';
                    echo '<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="addscore" value="Add Scores with Extras"> ';
                    echo '<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="addscore2" value="Add Scores without Extras">';
                echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Please investigate simplifying your code with arrays and loops.

Comment: Your function is concatenating strings, not summing up numbers. `parseFloat` them first.

Comment: There's no point in echoing entire HTML. You can just put it in the page... Only echo the variables from PHP. `<td style="..." name="<?php echo $i; ?>">`

Comment: Look in the JS ErrorConsole..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the value of the elements into integers:

Do this inside your function:

```
  var one = parseInt(document.getElementById(A).value), 10) || 0;
  var two = parseInt(document.getElementById(B).value, 10) || 0;
  var three = parseInt(document.getElementById(C).value, 10) || 0;
  var four = parseInt(document.getElementById(D).value, 10) || 0;
  var five = parseInt(document.getElementById(E).value, 10) || 0;
  var six = parseInt(document.getElementById(F).value, 10) || 0;
  var seven = parseInt(document.getElementById(G).value, 10) || 0;
  var eight = parseInt(document.getElementById(H).value, 10) || 0;
  var nine = parseInt(document.getElementById(I).value, 10) || 0;
  var ten = parseInt(document.getElementById(J).value, 10) || 0;
```

Comment: Good practice to always provide a radix to `parseInt`. You can get into trouble in older versions of JS if not (particularly with strings that start with `0`). Just do `parseInt(string, 10)` (since you probably want base 10), and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks guy, i understand my code is not very clean at the moment, but i am just looking for functionality first and then I will clean it up.

Comment: @strgrex, i tried using the code above in the Javascript function and it caused the page to stop producing any results at all.

Comment: I noticed that the parseInt() function produces a 'NaN' result until all text fields are full.  That is why i used Number() because it treats the empty text field as a zero

Comment: @knanz If you get 'NaN' result, you can try adding `|| 0` to the end of the lines. What this does is that if there's a blank value, the variable will default to integer 0. Otherwise, you can use the function isNan() to test whether the return value of a call will resolve to "NaN."

Comment: @Stegrex that fixed the NaN issue, however this code is still only calculating the rows and not the columns

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me out and I have posed the code below which solved my issue. Thanks everyone for your help.

```
function calcTotal(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,SUM) {

  var one = parseInt(document.getElementById(A) ? document.getElementById(A).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var two = parseInt(document.getElementById(B) ? document.getElementById(B).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var three = parseInt(document.getElementById(C) ? document.getElementById(C).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var four = parseInt(document.getElementById(D) ? document.getElementById(D).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var five = parseInt(document.getElementById(E) ? document.getElementById(E).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var six = parseInt(document.getElementById(F) ? document.getElementById(F).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var seven = parseInt(document.getElementById(G) ? document.getElementById(G).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var eight = parseInt(document.getElementById(H) ? document.getElementById(H).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var nine = parseInt(document.getElementById(I) ? document.getElementById(I).value : 0, 10) || 0;    
  var ten = parseInt(document.getElementById(J) ? document.getElementById(J).value : 0, 10) || 0; 

  var ans = one + two + three + four + five + six + seven + eight + nine + ten;      
  document.getElementById(SUM).innerHTML = ans;    
}
```